# Is there a Minecraft direction facing by hotkey solution?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I’ve already scoured the internet to the best of my searching ability for a client side Minecraft mod or solution that can set my camera rotational coordinates to pre-set directions with the press of a hotkey. Obviously I couldn’t find one so I come here to crowd source a solution. I am trying to make an automatic builder script and the facing method I have is unreliable. It’d be a blessing if that could be handled by the client so the script can operate on clicks and keyboard only without having to work on mouse movement. I’m asking here for solutions to the problem such as how it could be handled using the above inputs form the script. My next option would be to spend a Fiver to have a mod made for me because I’m at the point of pulling out hair and I have no coding experience.

Comment: I'm going to recommend you try to edit your question to remove specific references to a request for mod recommendations, as that's off-topic here.  You should be able to accomplish what you need with commands (i.e. no need for mods), so make the focus of your question on a general method to solve the problem, not is there a mod to solve the problem.

Comment: @MBraedley is that satisfactory?

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit better.  I think there's still some room for improvement, but I don't think the question should be closed anymore.

Comment: Tweakaroo has an option of snapping to rotational direction so you don't walk slightly sideways when laying a row of blocks. It's enabled/disabled by a hotkey, but it won't turn you to an arbitrary angle, only the nearest multiple of 45 degrees or whichever snap angle you've configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you actually asked is off-topic here (a mod recommendation) and I have never heard of a mod that does this (the closest would be a mod that adds a "look back" key), but maybe I can still help you with what you're really trying to do. You can abuse [a bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-150164) for an effect similar to what you described:

Press F3+P once to disable pausing on lost focus. Now you can use Alt+Tab to switch out of the game window without opening the pause menu. Look in the direction you want to "save" by opening the pause menu, chat, etc. and closing it again. Now you can move your mouse around normally, as long as you never open anything again that releases your cursor (this includes for example chest GUIs). Whenever you want to let your cursor snap back to the "saved" position, simply Alt+Tab out of the Minecraft window and back into it.